# How to convert an array of map into a map in JAVA8?

Tags: java, java-8

Right now I have

```
Map<String, String>[] map_array= [
{"k":"k1", "v":"v1"},
{"k":"k2", "v":"v2"}
]
```

How to use JAVA8 stream to convert it into

```
Map<String, String> map = {"k1" : "v1", "k2" : "v2"}
```

Update:
Sorry I was being unclear. The map_array contains two maps, and each map has two entries with the first one being key as "k", value as "k1" and second entry being key as "v" and value as "v1". Now I'm trying to merge them into one ImmutableMap<String, String> with key being "k1/k2" and value being "v1/v2". The implementation I have right now works, but I'm wondering if there's any cleaner way in JAVA8. Below is my implementation:

```
(Map<String, String> m : map_array) {
resault_map.put(m.get("k"), m.get("v"));
}
return result_map;
```

Comment: It's unclear what the contents of `map_array` are.  I know you show it in your question, but your pseudo-code is not very clear.  As it stands, it looks like you just want to know how to merge multiple maps that happen to be stored in an array together.  Is this correct?  Or are `k` and `v` actual keys in that map?

Comment: Do you mean that each map in the `map_array` has 2 keys - `k` and `v`?

Comment: @Sweeper correct! Just updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like each map in the array represents a key-value pair in the resulting map. Therefore, you can use `Collectors.toMap`, which accepts to functions - one that transforms an array element to the KVP's key, and one that that transforms an array element to the KVP's value:

```
public static Map<String, String> mapArraysToMap(Map<String, String>[] mapArray) {
    return Arrays.stream(mapArray).collect(Collectors.toMap(
        x -> x.get("k"),
        x -> x.get("v")
    ));
}
```

This is assuming that all array elements have a `k` and `v` key. You might want to `filter` out those that don't if that is possible in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much!. Every array element will have a k and v key.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a loop. Iterate over the `map_array` and then add each of them to the `map`.

Like this:

```
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map<String, String> mapFromArray : map_array) {
            map.putAll(mapFromArray);
        }
```

If you want to use Java8 steams, you can use the `reduce()` function. Code will look like this:

```
        Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(map_array).reduce(new HashMap<>(), (leftMap, rightMap) -> {
            leftMap.putAll(rightMap);
            return leftMap;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    m1.put("k1", "v1");
    Map<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    m2.put("k2", "v2");
    Map<String, String>[] m3 = Arrays.asList(m1, m2).toArray(new Map[0]);
    
    Map<String, String> result  = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Arrays.stream(m3).forEach(m -> result.putAll(m));
    
    System.out.println(result);
```

result map is what you are looking for. I think we can clean this code a bit more. But for the sake of example, this is the code